# Why is my jQuery transition is glitchy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery transition with a css overlay that will work fine if the user mouses over for a second or more....however if the user mouses over quickly then the overlay text stays put without the overlay background. Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(".cascade-t1").hover(function(){
$(".cascade-corner").fadeOut();
$(".overlay-t1").animate({"left": "-300px"}, 300, function(){
    $(".cascade-overlay-content").fadeIn(200);    
 });


}, function(){

   $(".cascade-corner").fadeIn();
    $(".cascade-overlay-content").fadeOut(200, function(){
    $(".overlay-t1").animate({"left": "130px"}, 300);    
   });

});
```

Here is [the script in action](http://jsfiddle.net/eY3yC/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eY3yC/1/ does this fix your problem (this will prevent animation stacking). But its not glitchy for me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/eY3yC/2/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is that you don't `fadeIn()` the `.overlay-t1` text until the mouseenter animation is done, and on mouseleave you `fadeOut()` the text out right away before the animation. When you move your mouse in and out faster than initial the animation the code will fade out the text and then fade it in again (the issue you're seeing).

One possible solution is to slightly alter your bottom (mouseleave) function to resemble your top (mouseenter) function more closely. Something like:

```
 $(".cascade-corner").fadeIn();
 $(".overlay-t1").stop(true, true).animate({"left": "130px"}, 300, function () {
     $(".cascade-overlay-content").fadeOut(200);
 });
```

The .stop() is there to keep the animation from playing over and over when someone spams the box.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/eY3yC/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how jquery animate works under the hood but it's possible it's using javascript to animate instead of css transitions. The benefit of css transitions is that it does all of the animation calculations before the animation begins and is hardware accelerated. Javascript is at the mercy of the scheduler at a very high level so it will always be choppy.

Try jquery transit.

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: He is asking why does the animation respond slowly when you move your cursor very quickly above the image.